# how to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{t^{s-1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} d t = \frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac12, \frac{s}{2}\right) $

Tags: integration

how to show that $$\int_0^1 \frac{t^{s-1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} d t = \frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac12, \frac{s}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\, \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Try making a change of variable $x = t^2$ which still has the integral from $0$ to $1$ and the integrand is exactly what you need to conclude that the integral has value shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard  definition is $B(a,b) = \int_0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1}\ dx$.  Try 
$t = x^{1/2}$ in your integral.

EDIT: For the equation $B(a,b) = \dfrac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$, see e.g.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function

Comment: and what about gamma function ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh Just use the definition $\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ with $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$